# AzerothCore: change the port of authserver

Tags: azerothcore

In AzerothCore it's possible to change the port of the `worldserver` by changing the value of `WorldServerPort` in `worldserver.conf`. Then the value in the `realm` table of the `acore_auth` database should be updated accordingly.

What about the `authserver` process? It defaults to `3724`. Is it possible to change it? How to then tell the client to connect to a different port?

Answer (score 1):

The client points by default to port `3724` when trying to authenticate (login). That's why this is also the default value for the `authserver` port.

In order to change this, you have to change the value of `RealmServerPort` from the `authserver.conf`

Then the client needs to be aware that it should point to a different port, that should be done by changing the `realmlist.wtf` file.

For example, let's assume that the value of `RealmServerPort` has been changed to `4000` and that your realmlist is currently:

```
set realmlist localhost
```

then it must be changed to:

```
set realmlist localhost:4000
```